# Running CAPL function in CANoe with comtypes gives an error

Tags: python, com, capl, canoe, comtypes

Right now I'm trying to call a CAPL function in CANoe with the CANoe COM API using the python comtypes package.

For this I created the following small short python program:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
c=CreateObject("CANoe.Application")
squareFunction=c.CAPL.GetFunction("square")
res=squareFunction.Call(5)
print(res==25)
```

This should call my short CAPL function:

```
int square(int x) {
   return x*x;
}
```

Unfortunately, the program yields in `c.CAPL.GetFunction("square")` an exception, in case the simulation is running in CANoe.

```
COMError: (-2147418113, 'Critical Error', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

If the simulation in CANoe is stopped, there is no error, but the call of the function yields `None`.

Does anyone knows, what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your function is defined in a CAPL block in the measurement-setup, not in the simulation-setup.

The application note *CANalyzer/CANoe as a COM Server* by Vector [link](https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-AND-1-117_CANoe_CANalyzer_as_a_COM_Server.pdf) states on page 15 that

> The assignment of a CAPL function to a variable can only be done in
>   the OnInit event handler of the Measurement object.

I.e. your `squareFunction` variable has to be initialized during the OnInit event. Similar to this:

```
def OnInit():
  self.squareFunction = c.CAPL.GetFunction("square")

c.Measurement.OnInit += CANoe._IMeasurementEvents_OnInitEventHandler(self.OnInit)
```

By this `OnInit` will be executed during measurement init and you can later execute `self.squareFunction.Call(5)`

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately, I'm not able to run your posted piece of code. _IMeasurementEvent_OnInitEventHandler seems to be unknown. Can you please post a minimal reproducible example, that complety shows what do?

Comment: You can add event handler in python as such:
```python
class MeasurementInitHandler:

    def OnInit(self):
        pass

win32com.client.WithEvents(canoe_measurement_instance, MeasurementInitHandler)
```